# jQuery how to declare variable outisdie function and use in function

Tags: jquery, variables, global, input-field

I need your help. I want to declare input field in variable outside function and the variable should work in function: for example

```
var name = $("#name").val();

function _testAlert()
{
    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: The example you gave should work just fine.

Comment: That should work. Check that name has a value, and make sure you're calling the function

Comment: Its Working One.

Comment: not working its shows in alert 'undefined'

Comment: What happens when you do `alert($("#name").val())` ? That is exactly doing the same like the code you wrote. So the problem is in your `$("#name").val()` and not in your variable declaration.

Comment: alert($("#name").val()) its working fine but when i declare this in var outside function its now working

Comment: alert($("#name").val()) - $("#name").val() both things are same so where is the problem

Comment: var  name =  $("#name").val(); its working fine if i use this inside function but when i declare outside function and then i call this inside function its not wkring

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="name" value="nabeel"/>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var name ;

$(document).ready(function() {
    name = $("#name").val();
   _testAlert();
});

function _testAlert()
{
    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: you can use you input field using a class name as well
for eg $(".name").val();

Answer (score 0):

Decalring a variable outside a function, like you did: `var name`, would scope it as "global". You can use it inside functions with no problem.

The problem is that you are **not waiting for the document to load** the input's value before assigning it to the `name` variable.

Try this:

```
var name ;

$(document).ready(function() {
    name = $("#name").val();
});

function _testAlert()
{
    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: Does the input with an ID `name` exist? Does it have a value when the document is loaded?

Comment: yes its exist the id name and field is not empty when i click submit

Answer (score 0):

your example looks good.It will work 100%.

Comment: Please read my answer and the PO's comments - your answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   var name =$("#mydemo").val();
   _testAlert();
   });
   function _testAlert()
   {
   alert(name);
   }
```

and another method id out side the document ready function

```
   var name =$("#mydemo").val();    
   function _testAlert()
   {
   alert(name);
   }
```